# Fix text-align in css for sections of header/footer

Tags: html, css, margin, text-align

I start a new web application project, where I have a html code like this:

**html:**

```
<footer>
    <section class="left">
        <h1>Copyright</h1>
        <span> Kleber Mota de Oliveira</span>
    </section>

    <section class="right">
        <h1>website</h1>
        <a href="http://klebermota.eti.br"> klebermota.eti.br</a>
    </section>
</footer>
```

**css:**

```
section {
  display: inline;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

full code: http://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/ee2nx7vc/

each section is placed at one side of the screen; but the text of the right side is being trimmed. In the header, the text isn't being aligned on the right as should.

Anyone can give a hint on how to fix that?

Comment: add some padding maybe?

Comment: You're centering the text in the `<ul>` in the header, which is why it is right aligned. And as far as the footer, you have a margin on the body element that is pushing things around. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your css

```
.right{
position:fixed; right: 7px;`}
```

and

```
.left{position:fixed; left: 7px;}
```

On jsfiddle it seems to be working ;)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the correct `line-height` will work. For now I reset it using:

```
* {line-height: 1;}
```

And it displays well:

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/qezuzanajo**

Answer (score 0):

```
section {
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
}

header section ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Sigmar One",cursive;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 2;
}
```